# Apache Roller Weblogger software

Tags: java, apache-roller

I am creating a blog using Apache Roller Weblogger software, am very new to this..
I am deploying it on the Tomcat, and m using the PostgreSQL database.. I did all the configuration in the `roller-custom.properties`.. If i give the url `http://localhost:8080/roller/` in the browser I am getting the resource not available error,
And in the `roller.log` file if I check, the database is loading fine..

Please if anybody have relevant suggestion please do share..

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  I setup the properties and followed the install guide but when I go to http://localhost:8080/roller/. I get a 404.  I am using the same setup except for the database I am using MySQL.  I will report any findings.

Comment: The 404 issue was fixed (had to restart the server).  I am getting a database error.  It seems roller will pull all the data from the properties file except for the connection URL (i did a straight copy from the documentation as well).

Comment: Yea u need to restart the server every time u made changs to the properties file, accrdng to "auto" or "manual" Initially i got the exception due to some problm in the properties file after rectifying my log file says all the db n the drivers r loaded, but gettng the /roller resource not found error

Comment: are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/rollerdb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and this to my jboss-web.xml:

```
   <resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/rollerdb</res-ref-name>
     <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/rollerdb-31</jndi-name>
   </resource-ref>
```